# How can I show this improper integral?

Tags: integration

I am writing a thesis about the brachystochrone for my studies. At the moment, I am unsure, how to solve an improper integral. The problem is modeled as follows.

$$ \begin{align*}
T &= \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{\sqrt{1+(y'(x_k))^2}}{\sqrt{2gy(x_k)}} \cdot \Delta x_k \\
&= \int_0^{x_b} \frac{\sqrt{1+(y'(x))^2}}{\sqrt{2gy(x_k)}} dx \\
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2g}} \int_0^{x_b} \frac{\sqrt{1+(y'(x))^2}}{\sqrt{y(x)}} dx
\end{align*} $$

We have a series of functions y with their derivatives y', of which one function y' minimizes the problem. BUT the Integral in it's borders 0 and b does not work, because in 0, the integral becomes infinitive. So I have to show the improper integral. My teacher told me to do it via the cauchy convergence. But for that I would have to solve the integral first, right (or not because it is not proved yet?). If I solve it, how can i solve with dx like shown in the equation? Can anybody help me with this? Other suggestions are welcome too.

Disclaimer: I am sorry for the formating and description of the problem. I am German and this is my first time on the website. Thanks for everyones advice.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. I've converted your picture to MathJax for you. You can click "Edit" to see how it's done. Also see the tutorial page https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/